# Magento Insert Image on WYSIWYG editor does not show images

Tags: magento-1.9, wysiwyg

I have been facing this issue on one of my client's Magento website.

On Magento admin panel WYSIWYG editor, when I click on Inert image icon and browse button, the Insert Image... pop up appears.

It displays the left side tree structure but the images are not displaying on the right side. Please refer to the screen shot.

I have 777 permission given for media folder and files.

I have cleared cache folder.

When I log the getStorageRoot() function, it returns,

/var/www/vhosts/domainname.com/httpdocs/media/wysiwyg/

[image]

Comment: what permissions does the `wysiwyg` folder have ?

Comment: WYSIWYG folder has 777 permission @DarkMukke

Comment: it looks like the whole panel on the right isnt loading not just the images, what cersion of Magento is this ?

Comment: You are right. Right side section has no html also when I firebugged it. I am on Magento 1.9.2.3 @DarkMukke

Comment: what are the permissions on `media/wysiwyg/.thumbs/` ?

Comment: 777 permission. All the files under wysiwyg editor has 777 permission. @DarkMukke